# gem install bson fail on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, bson, hanami

I'm trying to make a ruby hanami api using mongoid but the instalation fails because of bson.
I get this error

---

```
    compiling bytebuf.c
    compiling endian.c
    In file included from endian.c:18:
    bson-endian.h:109:1: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
      109 | uint16_t __bson_uint16_swap_slow(uint16_t v);
          | ^~~~~~~~
          | wint_t
    bson-endian.h:109:34: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'; did you mean
    'wint_t'?
      109 | uint16_t __bson_uint16_swap_slow(uint16_t v);
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
          |                                  wint_t
    bson-endian.h:110:1: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
      110 | uint32_t __bson_uint32_swap_slow(uint32_t v);
          | ^~~~~~~~
          | wint_t
    bson-endian.h:110:34: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'; did you mean
    'wint_t'?
      110 | uint32_t __bson_uint32_swap_slow(uint32_t v);
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
          |                                  wint_t
    bson-endian.h:111:1: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
      111 | uint64_t __bson_uint64_swap_slow(uint64_t v);
          | ^~~~~~~~
    bson-endian.h:111:34: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
      111 | uint64_t __bson_uint64_swap_slow(uint64_t v);
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
    endian.c:35:1: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
       35 | uint16_t __bson_uint16_swap_slow(uint16_t v)
          | ^~~~~~~~
          | wint_t
    endian.c:35:34: error: unknown type name 'uint16_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
       35 | uint16_t __bson_uint16_swap_slow(uint16_t v)
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
          |                                  wint_t
    endian.c:56:1: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
       56 | uint32_t __bson_uint32_swap_slow(uint32_t v)
          | ^~~~~~~~
          | wint_t
    endian.c:56:34: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?
       56 | uint32_t __bson_uint32_swap_slow(uint32_t v)
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
          |                                  wint_t
    endian.c:80:1: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
       80 | uint64_t __bson_uint64_swap_slow(uint64_t v)
          | ^~~~~~~~
    endian.c:80:34: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
       80 | uint64_t __bson_uint64_swap_slow(uint64_t v)
          |                                  ^~~~~~~~
    endian.c: In function '__bson_double_swap_slow':
    endian.c:109:4: error: unknown type name 'uint64_t'
      109 |    uint64_t uv;
          |    ^~~~~~~~
    In file included from endian.c:18:
    bson-endian.h:65:57: error: 'uint64_t' undeclared (first use in this function)
       65 | #  define BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(v) __builtin_bswap64 ((uint64_t)v)
          |                                                         ^~~~~~~~
    bson-endian.h:65:57: note: in definition of macro 'BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
       65 | #  define BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(v) __builtin_bswap64 ((uint64_t)v)
          |                                                         ^~~~~~~~
    bson-endian.h:65:57: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
    each function it appears in
       65 | #  define BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(v) __builtin_bswap64 ((uint64_t)v)
          |                                                         ^~~~~~~~
    bson-endian.h:65:57: note: in definition of macro 'BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
       65 | #  define BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(v) __builtin_bswap64 ((uint64_t)v)
          |                                                         ^~~~~~~~
    endian.c:112:32: error: expected ')' before 'uv'
      112 |    uv = BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(uv);
          |                                ^~
    bson-endian.h:65:66: note: in definition of macro 'BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE'
       65 | #  define BSON_UINT64_SWAP_LE_BE(v) __builtin_bswap64 ((uint64_t)v)
          |                                                                  ^
    make: *** [Makefile:244: endian.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2
```

---

My ruby version is 2.6.5 .

I have looked on internet for a solution but none of them worked. I tried to update my gem version using `gem update`.
and I tried to add `#include<stdint.h>` in the bson-endian.h.

How can I solve that problem.

Comment: How did you install Ruby? How did you install Ruby's development headers and the compiler toolchain for building gems?

Comment: with the ruby dev kit installer for windows on the ruby web site.

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Version 4.5.0 of BSON Gem. The Problem is in Version 4.6.0 of the Gem.

With bundle:
add `gem 'bson', '~> 4.5.0'` to Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Without: `gem install bson -v 4.5.0`.